# When should I say "post to" or "share with"?

Tags: meaning, word-choice

I need to explain that an app can post/share images to social networks and blogs with up to 5 services at the same time and that it's managed through *outh*.

Can anybody help me with some inspiration? I'm a bit stuck with that, especially if I should say *upload to -*, *send to-*, *post to -* or *share with* social networks.

Comment: What happens to the photo when you send it to, say, three different social networks?  Are you posting the photo once (e.g. to Flickr) and then referencing it from each of the three sites, or is it three separate transactions?

Comment: All your suggestions are fine, but *"upload to"* is probably better suited to "tech-savvy" readers than *"share with"*.

Comment: @MonicaCellio Three separate transactions.

Comment: @FumbleFingers Good point, thanks! Would you say *post to* instead of *upload to* if a message gets added to the image?

Comment: If it was me, I'd probably use "share" the first time I needed any of these words, and try to stick with it for consistency thereafter. If it really looks odd in some context, perhaps introduce **one** other word - "upload" should be fine, especially if the first time you use it comes very close behind "share". So your readers will quickly understand the usage if it's not something they're already familiar with.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The idea behind "uploading" and "sharing" is different.  If you really sending the image to their server it would be all right to use either "upload" or "share".  But if you keep the image on your server and send or add the html, javascript e.t.c code to social network,  "share" would be better.

Comment: I'm sending the image to their server. Optionally a title and caption can be added to the image. (Like in a blog post)

Comment: In this case, "upload to" may be  more suitable.

Answer (score 1):

I would use *post to*, *send to*, or (for slightly-more-technical users) *upload to*.  *Share* can mean the same thing, but it can also imply just linking -- you post the photo somewhere and then just show it (HTML img tag or the like) on the three sites.  So *share* is potentially ambiguous, and I would be concerned about users not realizing that they're posting the same photo in three different places.  (Most of the time they might not care, but occasionally they will -- either for reasons of bandwidth or maintenance (taking it down or protecting it later).)

Answer (score 1):

They could *submit* the image.

Answer (score 0):

*Sharing* happens when one server can either use or duplicate the content from another server. Note that I don't have to *upload* them. I could make a folder on my local machine shared, for instance.

*Uploading* happens when one or more files, usually more than just text, are transferred from a local machine to a server. Note that they don't have to be *shared*; I can upload files to DropBox without sharing them with anyone.

*Sending* happens asynchronously, for instance, with email.

*Post* comes from a particular HTTP verb, and usually means submitting something over the internet. You don't have to use HTTP to share or upload files; you could use FTP, for instance.

You've said that *outh* is managing whatever it's doing with the services. Is it sending images to those services? Posting them over HTTP (unlikely)? Uploading them to their servers? Or just sharing those files and relying on the services to come get them? Or is it perhaps *streaming* them?

This is why I avoid the word "manage" when programming or talking about apps.

If you're talking to non-tech-savvy people, *share* would be fine. They'll understand that terminology if they've come across Facebook.

You could also try http://programmers.stackexchange.com.